# Как найти опорные (ключевые) точки на фотографиях?

Tags: c, графика, c++, алгоритм

Есть несколько фото одного и того же объекта, но с разных ракурсов, разного размера и качества. Нужно программно определить ключевые точки на этих фото, причем без каких-либо шаблонов.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под ключевыми точками? Результат работы `Feature Extractor'ов` типа `SIFT / SURF`?

Comment: @Вячеслав1101, вам код привести? =)

Comment: код не обязательно. 
можно просто идею, или алгоритм.

Comment: Еще раз переспрошу - вот у вас есть последовательность фотографий. Что вы хотите получить **на выходе** алгоритма после его применения к этой последовательности?

Comment: нужно получить кординаты точек, которые присутствуют на каждом из этих фото. такие точки за которые можно "зацепиться".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Вячеслав1101](/users/8151/%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B21101)](/users/8151/%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B21101)

- В таком случае лучше `SIFT / SURF` еще ничего не придумали в силу инвариантности этих кейпоинтов относительно многих типов трансформаций. Реализации присутствуют в библиотеках типа `OpenCV`.
- См. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF и http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/eccv06.pdf
- В качестве более быстрого аналога можно попробовать [**ORB [2011]**](https://willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf), который также реализован в `OpenCV`, см. http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html?highlight=orb#ORB

Comment: Можете посоветовать статью по реализации алгоритма SURF?

Answer (score -1):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что задачу можно свести к нахождению собственных векторов матриц, полученных из фотографий. Но я не уверен, к сожалению.